# Ajax error callback called when valid JSON is retuned

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

**In my js file I'm calling the below:**

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "application/json",
          url: "php/parseFunctions.php",
          data: {data:queryObj},
          success: function(response) {
             theFunction(response);
          },
          complete:  function(response) {
             theFunction(response);
          },
          error: function(response) {
             theFunction(response); // response = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"found":0}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"

          }
    });
```

**In my `php/parseFunctions.php` I have:**

```
$returnResults = array(); 
$returnResults['found']=count($returnResults);  
echo  json_encode($returnResults);
exit;
```

I expect the `success` callback to get called and for `response` to be the json object `{"found":"0"}`

Instead, the `error` callback gets called and  `response = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"found":"0"}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}`

I've read that this will happen if the returned JSON is invalid, but I don't feel like it is.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your `dataType` attribute. You have set it to `"application/json"`. While this is a value mimeType value, the `$.ajax` function is expecting one of the following predefined values: `xml, json, script, or html` as listed in [the relevant page of the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Try having your call to `$.ajax` look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "php/parseFunctions.php",
      data: {data:queryObj},
      success:{...},
      complete:{...},
      error:{...}
});
```

Comment: Wow, I can't imagine how that got there and I feel dumb for not seeing it, thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't feel bad! It's a very valid type of string to see around web applications - It wouldn't necessarily jump out as something problematic. Glad to help! Happy coding!